# request_contact TELEGRAM delivery

Tags: ruby, bots, telegram

Got a problem with the delivery of the message with the phone user, although other messages are good. Using saved 100% working version - the same problems.

Way by getUpdates receives all messages except as answers  request_contact: true too:

https://api.telegram.org/bottoken/getUpdates

Request Code bot:

```
Telegram::Bot::Types::KeyboardButton.new(text: 'Allow me see your phone', request_contact: true)
```

[deliver problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZ01h.png)

Comment: It's seems a client-side error. Try to use Android / iOS client or ask to Telegram Support.